# Is there any comunity distribution of linux that i can run on hp proliant dl160 g6?

Tags: centos

I have to put to work an HP proliant DL 160 G6. I'm triyng centos but i get the following error:

"ERST: failed to get error log address range".
Some pople said that is the RAID array that generating the problem. I changed from raid to AHCI and i still get the same error. So is there any free distribution that works with tis server?

I need this to run a simple web server for an webapp.

Comment: Use software raid.

Comment: The only two Linux's supported on that hardware are RHEL and SLES - presumably versions from at least five years ago - for that's when these servers became end-of-sale. As this site is for professional sysadmins/designers in production environments we tend to use supported/supportable systems - and yours isn't any longer sorry.